# CSS gradient not appearing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

A CSS gradient will not show up in Firefox. It appears fine in Chrome. Do you know how this would be fixed?

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when you use obsolete and non-standard vendor prefixes without including the modern one. Just use `background-image: linear-gradient(...)`

Comment: Please stop defacing your post. Instead, edit it to mention the security problem or resolve that problem. But please do not edit it in a way that invalidates the efforts people have made in the answer and comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are using -webkit-linear-gradient which is for webkit only, and won't work with Firefox.

Use linear-gradient as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient